# How can I make a heading more legible on a real estate background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mobile, user-experience, posters, readability

This is a billboard design I'm working on (to be used on highways). I think the heading on this is a little less legible (I just feel so. Is it really?).

So is there any way to make it more legible? I tried putting a black overlay above building layer and reduce it's opacity to make the white text more legible, but increasing the opacity makes the building less visible. (There's still an overlay with 20% opacity)

1. **So what can be some the other possibilities to make it more clear and readable?**

One more query related to readability is:
The number on the footer is **Indian mobile number**. I've used dots to separate it. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#India), they've mentioned we can use a hyphen:

> Mobiles: Written as AAAAA-BBBBB for ease of remembering

2. **Given that all, can I use periods (or hyphens) at TWO places instead of ONE, to separate the number into 3 easily readable parts? OR would it make it confusing and incorrect format?** (Personally I feel it more attractive and beautiful, but I don't know if I'm breaking any mobile number rules by doing it).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Heading

There are many ways to make it more visible or giving it a bigger visual hierarchy. One of the neat way is with a duplicating shadow.

- Duplicating the text
- Moving it down-left
- Filling it with black or the dark blue from the sign

### Phone number

Personally I would try to eliminate the noise in number information.

- Inserting a phone icon at the beginning
- Increasing the tracking
- Separating the number groups

[image]

**Semi transparent patch**

[image]

Comment: 1. Thank you. This is really nice approach, using a solid shadow. But it makes it a little old fashioned?

Comment: 2. That is also right. But still any idea about the query? Using dots and hyphens is incorrect?

Comment: The shadow is never old fashioned, in fact it is with us since we are in this world . I think using dots or whatever in phone numbers is right, but as I wrote in the answer is unnecessary visual noise, especially in long distance reading signs.

Comment: 1. Seems right. I'll think about it. 2. Even when 534 & 232 & 444 has no special meaning except easy to remember, still there's nothing incorrect by using dots/hyphens?

Comment: Like in USA, separated parts have different logics and meaning.

Comment: As in the whole world, but I don't think there's a legal norm that forces to use a separation character, that's why I aim for legibility.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for the kind help, as always :)

Comment: I'll mark it correct if I don't see any other better response.

Comment: I disagree with the "insert phone icon". You wouldn't insert a mailbox icon if there was *only* an address. Or insert a computer icon if there was *only* a URL. Icons can be *very* helpful when there's more than one contact method, but for a single phone number, an icon is merely visual clutter in my opinion.

Comment: I took care about long distance reading, points or any small element can be noise and groups of isolated numbers may not mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This post if full of random image examples from a Google Image Search. Images are copyrighted to their original creators. **No license or permission should be attributed to any images in this posting**.</sup>

---

## Readability

Anytime I get the urge to put a drop shadow on type so it can be read, the design isn't solid. Type should be readable *without* something like drop shadows. Now that is **not** to say using drop shadows is a mistake. It's not always. It is merely *my preference* that things should work *without* a drop shadow... then if one is added, it's *secondary* and *not* critical to readability.

In order to make type work *without* a drop shadow there are a number of varying techniques I feel are available. Which option works best is highly dependent upon the photo and the amount of text to be used.

---

The key, for me, to using a photograph behind text is all in the photo. Not all photographs are suitable for such usage and it takes care to use the *right* photo much of the time. And the method of applying type may change based upon the photo.

## Narrow Tonal Range

Fist, I'd ensure the photo has a good general contrast for my usage. That means its general tonal range is either dark or light - therefore allowing a contrasting type color to "pop" as much as possible.

For darker photos, reverse type should work well if the photo has the desired tonal darkness to it. Roughly a photo that is 50% dark and darker across *most* of its surface.

> [image] [image]

... or the converse for dark text. 
<sub>(Finding examples if dark text on light photos isn't easy via Google. This isn't a "stunning" example.)</sub>

> [image]

---

## Large Areas of Similar Tone

If the photo simply does not have an overall narrow tonal range is is a mix of dark and light areas, then **placement** of the type can be key. Using a photo with a *large area* of a similar tone and them placing the text within that area can work well.

> [image] [image] [image] [image]

Magazine covers tend to use this technique quite often:

> [image] [image] [image]

---

## Visual elements

Another option is to design a "container" for any text so that you can push the contrast overall between the photo and the text. This can be done in many ways and, to me, is *always preferable* to drop shadows.

> [image] [image] [image] [image]

I alway prefer tonal alterations to the image, such as darker areas or screened areas over solid colored elements, but that's more a matter of preference I think.

---

## Alter the photo

Another option is to alter the photo to be used giving it a general tonal range you *can* use when otherwise it would not work.

> [image] [image] [image] [image]

---

With all these techniques, the use of things like strokes or drop shadow is not really necessary for readability.

For *that* particular photo....

- First I'll state that I do *not* think the contrast on your image is bad. The reverse type over the building is *perfectly legible*. There's some slight visual "noise" merely due to the windows of the building. That pattern behind the type seems to cause a sort of "vibration" when reading, but it's very minor. However, I do realize this clearly isn't your *actual* type and that may be more problematic than your sample.

I would utilize the large area of **sky** and the solid color on the right you have. I, personally, would not do any sort of bottom banner. My design sense tells me that bottom area is clutter and visually "noisy" overall.

[image]

This is an **absolutely horrible** cover up of the type you had on the photo. The *actual* photo may provide better options. **I'd like a different crop on the photo**, but I don't know if that is available to you. I'm not overly fond of the bottom portion of the photo and would prefer to show a bit more ground and well as show the right edge of the buildings.

In the end, this is highly readable in my opinion.

---

**Regarding phone number separators....**

Many "business people" will tend to think the periods will confuse readers. In my experience it **doesn't**. The periods are fine.

I've created *thousands of pieces* with phone numbers on them. Sometimes I use the periods, sometimes hyphens, sometimes nothing, sometimes a totally different element. **The alteration of the separator has had no direct discernible effect on ROI.**

The imperative part of the phone number (for English speakers at least) is the breaking of the digits. `XXX XXX XXXX` or `X XXX XXX XXXX` is almost always seen as a phone number. As long as you don't break the pattern of `3` `3` `4`, you can really use almost anything as a separator character if you want.

Comment: Did you read that it will be used on highways? Many of your examples are useless in long distance reading.

Comment: Actually, I disagree. many my examples show **methods** which are very useful for billboards. The particular google images I pulled to show the *method* may not make great billboards, but that wasn't the intention. (And I didn't down vote your answer merely because I disagree with you [that icon is absolutely horrid].. but oh well).

Comment: Fortunately none of the elements of my answer are my designs, neither the ad nor the icon 

Comment: I was referring to the *usage* of the icon.. which *is* your design `:)`

Comment: I think we have different opinions about what design means. I have 615 answers in GD.SE and in none of them I have designed, and I do not intend to do so, for several reasons, the main one is respect for the person who ask, their work and the own learning (or evolution). Giving graphic ideas is the best way to express a concept, specially for our profession, but this is very, very far away from designing. Anyway, I respect your comment.

Comment: @Scott  *This is an absolutely horrible cover up of the type you had on the photo.* You mean typing on the building instead of some empty/even space with not much noise?

Secondly, *As long as you don't break the pattern of 3 3 4* Did you say that for a specific country like USA or even for my example (it's Indian mobile number)?

Comment: @VikasKumar I meant *my work* to remove the type from the photo was horrible. It was done quickly merely to get rid of the type and show an example. ---- And I can only comment on US phone numbers.. 3 3 4 is fine for the US. I can't comment on other countries.

Comment: OMG! I didn't notice you removed the type from building! Photoshop?

Comment: I found your view about bottom footer helpful. Your other approaches for making text legible were also helpful. But I found @Danielillo 's answer more helpful for this particular problem.

Comment: Whatever works `:)`